# Use Opencv on Android

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, android-ndk

I have found this code: https://github.com/mintuhouse/FinMan/blob/master/src/unix/imp.cpp which is a class for preprocessing an image with a receipt using OpenCV.

I wanted to ask: how can I use it in an android application which takes a photo and saves it as bitmap?

I tried to understand what the class is doing and tried to write this procedure in android. But it's little difficult because it has some functions such as `cvZero(image)` that I couldn't find in OpenCV for Android. Any ideas?

Also, I have tried the NDK, but I couldn't figure out how my bitmap file and this class would communicate after the NDK-build. I'm confused! Any help?

Comment: that cpp sample is using the old c-api, the android/java code is based on the newer c++ api. also the above code seems to do *much* more that you seem to want to do.

Comment: What i want is to capture a receipt and extract the items and their prices. But because the tesseract engine i use don't give me satisfying results i thought that a good filtering of the image would give better results. So i found this class which makes the filtering and i wanted to try write it on android/java code. what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

In old opencv api all functions, structures, etc. started from prefix "cv" to show that they are part of OpenCV library. In version 2.0 api changed, and all functiones, structures, classes etc are in namespace "cv", so in c++ you can access them by using this prefix, for example "cv::Point" or "cv:imread(...)". Old cvZero function now is accessible the same way or eventually is a method(probably static) of Mat class - so you can use it this way: myMat.zero(...) or Mat::zero(...). In Java it should be similar - try myMat.zero(...) or Mat.zero(...).